# What's the rpm/yum equivalent of `aptitude why`?

Tags: linux, package-management, yum, rpm

On .deb managed systems one can use

```
$ aptitude why <package>
```

to find out what installed package required the installation of `<package>`

for example:

```
$ aptitude why python
i   xdiagnose Depends python (< 2.8)
```

*IMHO `$ python -c 'import this'` gives a better answer to the question 'why python', but I digress...*

What would be the equivalent on rpm/yum governed systems (in my case Fedora)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ rpm -q --whatrequires python
```

Comment: The output does not look complete, though. In my case, `rpm -q --whatrequires kmod-nvidia-340xx` returns nothing, but `yum erase kmod-nvidia-340xx` wants to erase a huge amount of dependent packages.

Comment: Don't know what yum erase does. My manpage says we've migrated to dnf. But maybe it erases the dependencies of the packages itself too?

Comment: From my `man`:
`Are  used  to  remove  the  specified packages from the system as well as removing any packages which
              depend on the package being removed.`
Dependencies of the package are not supposed to be removed. I don't know where this strange behavior comes, though...

Comment: Apologies for posting to an old thread. Adding for folks who read this in the future. `yum erase _package_` will erase the package and all dependencies of that package. `yum deplist _package_` shows this.  `rpm --whatrequires python` shows a list of packages that NEED python to run, not the packages that python is dependent upon.